# how to make a single class for table view and inherit in all other classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, tableview

I want to have table view in around 5 screens with same layout. 
what should be the best approach? Should i make a single class and then inherit other view controllers with that class? or make table view in each screens with separate coding?

Comment: same layout means the same cell, and the same type of item details in the cell (same model class)? this is too broad a question...

Comment: Cell details would be same in all screens , like 1 image and 1 textview

Comment: You can create a superclass view controller where you can put common UI customizations, logic and methods for each subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a subclass of UITableViewCell and use that as your cell layout through your app.

If you need the UITableView to have exactly the same properties throughout, you could also create a UITableView extension like this (in Swift)

```
extension UITableView {
    class func defaultTableView() -> UITableView {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        // Setup your default tableView properies here
        return tableView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what is similar between your 5 forms.

1. If you have 5 different forms with the same tableview on each (and with the same data), but the other controls on forms may be different then the best approach is make one TTableView controller. Then put ViewContainer on each of 5 forms and then make embedded segue from containers to your separate TableViewController.
2. If you have 5 different forms with different tableview but this table view looks similar, the best approach is to make one UITableViewCell with its own xib and use it in all 5 TableViews (as in answer of tskippe).